# OpenWRT on Teltonika RUT230/240

Tags: router, openwrt, firmware

Is it possible, on either the Teltonika RUT230 or 240, to either install regular OpenWRT packages inside the routers' "RutOS" variant of OpenWRT, or, if not, to instead install vanilla OpenWRT firmware on them?

The RUT500 and RUT5xx devices have [entries in OpenWRT's table of hardware](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start?dataflt%5BBrand*%7E%5D=teltonika). There are unfortunately no entries for any other Teltonika device and while Teltonika's website [makes it clear](https://teltonika.lt/product/rut230/) that "RutOS" is based on OpenWRT, additional info on that distribution does not seem to exist publically - at least I've not been able to find anything.

Answer (score 2):

I've now found out that Teltonika are trying to do the right thing. That is, for all their devices that are using FLOSS operating systems as their firmware, they're providing [downloads of their modified sources](https://teltonika.lt/gpl/). So the answer to both parts of my question is yes.